# Что имеется ввиду, что сайт на html5?

Tags: html, html5

Не ругайте за вопрос, но я только начал учится и мне не понятно, что такое сайт на html5.
В моем понимании html5 - это convas, который позволяет использовать для рендера мощь GPU.
И получается, что сайт на html5, это сайт, который ПОЛНОСТЬЮ ( текст, да и вообще все-все ) нарисован на конвасе?

Comment: не convas, a canavas во-первых. Во-вторых, этот самый canvas - лишь одна из элементов html5, и html5 ни в коем случае не то же самое, что canvas. Это вообще очень разные вещи, надо сказать. Html5 - это  стандарт языка разметки html. Он включает в себя много всяческих новшеств по сравнению с предыдущей, четвертой версией. А выражение "сайт сделан на html5@ означает всего лишь, что сайт разработан с использованием этого самого стандарта, и в его разметке используются присущие именно html5 элементы. Помимо canvas этих элементов еще целая куча.

Comment: То есть получается, как был html, так он им и остался и сказать - сайт на html5, это как сказать - сайт?

Comment: ну вот представьте, что был у вас Запорожец, а вы взяли и накопили с обедов на Майбах. В общем-то можно  сказать, что и раньше у вас была машина, и теперь тоже машина, и, дескать, ничего не поменялось. Однако все же разница между "запором" и Майбахом довольно существенна

Comment: Html5 это все тот же html только с добавлением функций. То есть был выпущен новый стандарт языка разметки и новые браузеры должны его поддерживать, кто не поддерживает - тот устарел. А канвас и т.д. это просто нововведения.

Comment: Вот был у меня html-запорожец, сам не чего не умел, все анимации в нем делал js+css. Теперь у меня html5-Майбах... И хочется поинтересоваться - теперь он анимировать сам умеет? Или он так и остался, тем же запорожцем, который прославился в сотни раз больше только из-за конваса и GPU?

Comment: не кОнвас, а кАнвас, второй раз уже говорю. И потом (также во второй раз уже) **html5 не ограничивается одним лишь тэгом canvas**, в этом стандарте есть много разных других нововведений. Что вы так прицепились к этому canvas?

Comment: @aco про мультиплатформу не понял. А по поводу Html лучше подойдет такая аналогия. Html - набор деталей для самолета. Html5 - улучшенный набор деталей для самолета. Самолет - твой сайт. Пилот - браузер. Ты можешь делать самолет из старых деталей или использовать новые, чтобы самолет мог выполнять новые маневры, но для всего этого нужен еще и пилот иначе самолет не полетит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сайт на html5 - это сайт, html код которого соответствует стандартам html5.
Стандарт - это правила, по которым создается код.

В стандарте html5, по сравнению с 4 версией, введены некоторые новые элементы и несколько изменен подход, к структуре документа.

Например в нем с помощью тегов `<header></header>, <footer></footer>, <nav></nav>, <sidebar></sidebar>` можно описать соответствующие элементы страницы, что делает код нагляднее и проще для восприятия людей и поисковых роботов.
В `<article>` помещается основное содержание страницы.
В каждом из этих разделов теперь допустимо применять свою вложенность заголовков h1, h2 (в предыдущем стандарте допускался лишь один h1 на страницу).
Более подробно почитать о стандарте html5 можно например здесь: http://htmlbook.ru/html5

Чтобы проверить соответствует ли код стандарту html5 - можно использовать онлайн-валидатор, например http://html5.validator.nu который укажет на все ошибки и несоответствия стандарту.

И html5 не связан непосредственно с рендерингом и отрисовкой элементов. Этим занимается клиентский браузер.